# how to installed httpd package using Ansible in client in ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

while installing httpd package using below ansible command i am getting

```
"appserver | FAILED! => {
    "cache_update_time": 1556452826,
    "cache_updated": false,
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "'/usr/bin/apt-get -y -o \"Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef\" -o \"Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold\"     install 'mini-httpd'' failed: E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)\nE: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?\n",
    "rc": 100,
    "stderr": "E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)\nE: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?\n",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)",
        "E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?"
    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

ansible command:

```
ansible all -m apt  -a "name=mini-httpd state=present"
```

Comment: The error happens because the user you are using to run the command is not allowed to write on the lock files of dpkg. Even at the end of the error message clearly says **are you root?**. Try running the same command as `root`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit*: the below was still true up to ansible 2.7, although the `-s | --sudo` option was already announced as deprecated for a while and still arround for compatibility. Since ansible 2.8 you can only use `-b | --become`:

```
ansible all -b -m apt  -a "name=mini-httpd state=present"
```

---

> E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
>   E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock

Installing apt packages requires to be root on the target machine. If the current user you are connecting with on the target machine has sudo capabilities, try:

```
ansible all -s -m apt  -a "name=mini-httpd state=present"
```

And see `ansible --help` for all other privileges escalation option if this does not solve your issue.

Comment: The answerer below seems to have a valid point, although I cannot seem to trace when ansible `--sudo` option was deprecated in favour of `--become`

Comment: Well actually this was marked as deprecated long ago  (around 2015) but It was removed in ansible 2.8. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`-s` is not valid and if you want to install package you would need to be root.
You will the need option `--become`.

So the command will look like this for `apache2` on Ubuntu

```
ansible all -m apt -a "name=apache2 state=present" --become
```

Comment: This is indeed true now, but at the time the answer of Zeitounator was written `-s` was the equivalent of `--sudo`, that was _Run the command as the user given by -u and sudo to root._

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. As updated above, the `-s` option was still arround for compatibilité up to ansible 2.7. It was removed in ansible 2.8.